# Share one android device for developing

Tags: titanium

We are several people (in different cities) developing on titanium. We have only one device to check how the application works on a real device. 
Can we share somehow one device to check how application works on a real device?

The idea is to have one PC with remote access and Titanium running with connected git\mercurial repositories. Android device connected to this PC by USB. The user connects by Remote Control to the PC, pulls data from repository and runs application on the device.

The problem that we have is how to get access to screen of the Android device on the PC to control it.

Does someone have an idea how it could be organized?

Answer (score 0):

This link (http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) says it will help, but it has limitations.  I guess this solution would make sense if you are doing most of the testing on the local emulator and the physical device is a final check for functionality.

Comment: yep, i used it, but unfortunately it doesn't let me control the device, only share the screen (with great lags btw =( ).